# why does this simple div change the object value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

nowadays the world is about contradiction and now I'm experiencing it in the rails 4.

```
<%= content_tag_for :tr , @person.products do |i| %>
  <td>
    <%= i.id %> //Line 1
    <div class="editform hide">
    <%= i.id %> //Line 2
    </div>
  </td>
<% end %>
```

the output of line 1 changes as the loop iterates but the output of line 2 is constant and doesn't change( and its value is the value of first iteration ). what is going on here guys?

**UPDATE:**

```
output of line1: 9 , 10 , 11 ,12
output of line2: 9 , 9 , 9 , 9
```

**Update2:**
I just realized that the problem comes from the editform class which is related to jquery popover.when I change the class name of that div, the problem get solved. here is my code to render popover:

```
$(function () {
  $('.label-with-popover-edit').popover({ 
    html : true,
    content: function() { return $(".editform").html(); } , 
    placement:  'top'
  });
```

**UPDATE3:**
I just found something else.if I remove the hide class and let the div to be visible, then the output on the page does not equal to the output on the popover !!!! I'm sure that the jquery is the source of the problem.

Comment: Can you post the actual output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug, after loading the page, there are a bunch of divs with the same class and jquery popover loads the first one.